# Glances psutil warning scrolling the console

Tags: python, exception, warnings, psutil

```
Glances v2.11.1 with psutil v5.4.3
```

> /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_pslinux.py:1152: RuntimeWarning: ignoring OSError(6, 'No such device or address')
>     warnings.warn("ignoring %r" % err, RuntimeWarning)

OS is antegos running 4.15.3-2ARCH Kernel.

Why is it a problem? It is scrolling the console.

Temporary fix: I commented the message of the exception.

The issue seems to be related to the fan speed. I am running thinkfan and tlp.

Is there any real fix? I did not notice any problems using glances.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue with *glances*. 
I got ride of the scrolling issue by starting *glances* like this:

> glances 2>/dev/null

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

The David Tourrel is a nice workaround, and it's working, but the same issue is something that happened to me since yesterday, when I had to uninstall/reinstall glances.

I still don't know why it's happening. it seems related to the sensors (heat? fan) idk). When looking for in the internet I found the

> glances --disable-sensors

makes appear the warning message just once during its startup, and not during the running.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to try run it this way by typing in terminal:

```
sudo glances --enable-plugin sensors
```

or just

```
sudo glances
```

Running it as user, without sudo/root privileges, automatically shows the error mentioned above. It looks like gathering data from sensors via psutil can be done only as an elevated user.